# ASP.net dropdownlist unexpected event firing behavior

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I'm experiencing some odd behavior with drop down boxes and I'm hoping someone could explain what's going on.  I have a datarepeater  that builds out a table of rows.  Each row has a dropdownlist (hidden) and a linkbutton (not hidden) in a cell.  The expected behavior is that when a user clicks the linkbutton for a specific cell, it fires a server command.  This command does a few things but also sets the selected value of the DDL and then sets it visible and sets itself (the linkbutton) hidden.  The problem is that the dropdownlist's event should fire every time the selected index changes.  But, what ends up happening is that it only fires the first time the user changes the DDL value.  After that, the event will stop firing.  Also, all of this is in a usercontrol and all the code is inside an updatepanel.  As I mention in the code example, if I do not change the ddl value, in the linkbutton event, this behaviors stops but then the DDL wont have the correct value set.  Here is my code:

Linkbutton event:

```
Protected Sub edit_click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    Dim btn As LinkButton = CType(sender, LinkButton)
    Dim userId As String = btn.CommandArgument
    Dim ds As New List(Of myObject)
    Dim currentChoice As New myObject
    Dim parent As RepeaterItem = CType(btn.Parent, RepeaterItem)

    Dim lbl As Label = CType(parent.FindControl("userId"), Label)
    Dim ma As DropDownList = CType(parent.FindControl("ddlMustApprove"), DropDownList)
    Dim maLbl As Label = CType(parent.FindControl("mustApprove"), Label)

     'just get a list of values to chose from
    ds = Session("userNotificationDS")
    currentChoice = ds.Find(Function(p As myObject) p.User.NetworkID = userId)

    With maLbl
        .Width = 100
        .BorderColor = Drawing.Color.DarkBlue

    End With

    'if I disable this next line, everything works fine (but then the correct selection wont be chosen)
    ma.Text = currentChoice.MustApprove
    ma.CssClass = ""
    maLbl.Visible = False
End Sub
```

DDL change event:

```
Protected Sub selection_Change(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) 
    Dim cnt As DropDownList = CType(sender, DropDownList)
    Dim parent As RepeaterItem = CType(cnt.Parent, RepeaterItem)
    Dim maLbl As Label = CType(parent.FindControl("mustApprove"), Label)
    Dim userId As Label = CType(parent.FindControl("userId"), Label)
    Dim ds As New List(Of myObject)

    'just gets the value to set the DDL to
    ds = Session("userNotificationDS")

    For Each i As myObjectIn ds
        If (i.User.NetworkID = userId.Text) Then
            i.MustApprove = cnt.SelectedValue
        End If
    Next

    maLbl.Visible = True
    cnt.CssClass = "hidden"
    Session("userNotificationDS") = ds
    bindData(ds)
End Sub
```

Here is the Datarepeater in the front end code:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="dataRepeateUsers" runat="server"  EnableViewState="false" OnItemCreated="RepeaterItemCreated" >
<HeaderTemplate> 
          .... column headers
</HeaderTemplate>  
     <ItemTemplate>  
        <tr  class="listcolor">
          <td style="border:0px; border-right:1px solid  #808080  ; border-bottom:0px solid #808080;">
            <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlMustApprove" CssClass="hidden"  OnTextChanged="selection_Change" EnableViewState="true" AutoPostBack="true" >
                <asp:ListItem Text="True" Value="True"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="False" Value="False"></asp:ListItem>
           </asp:DropDownList>
          <asp:label ID="mustApprove" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "MustApprove") %>'></asp:label>
         </td>
       </tr>
     </ItemTemplate>
     <AlternatingItemTemplate>
        <tr  class="listcolor">
          <td style="border:0px; border-right:1px solid  #808080  ; border-bottom:0px solid #808080;">
            <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlMustApprove" CssClass="hidden"  OnTextChanged="selection_Change" EnableViewState="true" AutoPostBack="true" >
                <asp:ListItem Text="True" Value="True"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="False" Value="False"></asp:ListItem>
           </asp:DropDownList>
          <asp:label ID="mustApprove" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "MustApprove") %>'></asp:label>
         </td>
       </tr>             
     </AlternatingItemTemplate> 
 <FooterTemplate>  
</FooterTemplate>  
    </asp:Repeater>
```

My code is written in VS 2010 using .Net 4.0 and AjaxControlToolkit 4.1.60919.

Thanks
jason

Answer (score 0):

```
ma.Text = currentChoice.MustApprove
```

replace this line with the following one.

```
if(ma.items.FindByText(currentChoice.MustApprove) != null)
{
ma.SelectedIndex = -1;
ma.items.FindByText(currentChoice.MustApprove).selected = true;
 }
```

Just set the selectedindex of the dropdown as -1 like above.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  This gives an error of:  Cannot have multiple items selected in a DropDownList.

Comment: I tried changing your code to:
If (Not ma.Items.FindByText(currentChoice.MustApprove) Is Nothing) Then
For Each i As ListItem In ma.Items
i.Selected = False
Next
ma.Items.FindByText(currentChoice.MustApprove).Selected = True
End If

Although this prevents the "Multiple Selected" error, I still do not get the dropdownlist selectedIndexChanged event firing after the fist attempt.

Comment: Although that gets rid of the error, I still get no post back event firing